# DateTime.ParseExact doesn't work for "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have System.DateTime.Now stored in a variable called **StartDate** (variable is of type DateTime?).

I am converting it to string as below:

```
string temp = StartDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Now the temp has value in "**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**".

Now I want to again convert string **temp** to **DateTime** so, I am doing as below:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(temp,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",null)
```

but this doesn't work.

It always returns date in a same format as System.DatTime.Now. It should return value in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format.

Comment: Assuming the format should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, [I can't reproduce the problem.](http://rextester.com/VYU83873)

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? does not compile? formatexception? result off by four hours? please clarify.

Comment: Blind guess - try `DateTime.ParseExact(temp,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ? Do you have some strange current culture?

Comment: [Here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9wk1k), in case it helps.

Comment: Alreday tried with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. It doesn't make any difference. It always returns date same as System.DateTime.Now

Comment: Why do you expect it to return something else then `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: The format returned is 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'. It should be yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss as I am using DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: For ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD...) there is no need of `ParseExact` and format - you can use simple `Parse`.

Comment: If your `DateTime` is rendered as 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss' it is because the format provider that is used when calling `ToString()` has that as it's format. An instance of `DateTime` has no notion of it's format. Calling `DateTime.ParseExact()` will not change that.

Comment: I already tried with Simple 'DateTime.Parse' it didn't work

Comment: What is the **exact** value of temp?

Answer (score 3):

A value of type `DateTime` doesn't *have* a particular format. That date-and-time is stored as a couple of integer values (*not* one for each component, but much more compact).

When you parse a string, that date represented in that string is stored as those integers.

Only when you do a `.ToString()` (possibly with some format) you get a *string representation* of that date in a particular format.

When you hover over the DateTime value in the debugger, you see the result of a plain `.ToString()`, using some specific current culture.

The difference between `Parse` and `ParseExact` is that Parse tries several formats (and may fail on a string like "2/3/2017" - FEB 3rd or 2nd MAR?) while with ParseExact you supply one or more formats yourself. In both cases you end up with a value of the same `DateTime` type.